# D3: move circle between two different g elements in force layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js, transition, force-layout

I have two `g` elements each containing circles. Circles are organized using `force.layout`. The `g` elements are transitioning.

You can see here: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7Nxpp/6/). Reduced code:

```
    var dots = svg.selectAll(".dots")
    .data(data_groups)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "dots")
    .attr("id", function (d) {
     return d.name;
    })
    ...
    .each(addCircles);

    dots.transition()
    .duration(30000)
    .ease("linear")
    .attr("transform", function (d, i) {
        return "translate(" + (150 + i * 100) + ", " + 450 + ")";
    });

    function addCircles(d) {

        d3.select(this).selectAll('circle')
        .data(data_circles.filter(function (D) {
            return D.name == d.name
        }))
        .enter()
        .append('circle')
        .attr("class", "dot")
        .attr("id", function (d) {
            return d.id;
        })
        ...
        .call(forcing);
    }

    function forcing(E) {

        function move_towards(alpha) {
            ...
        }

        var force = d3.layout.force()
        .nodes(E.data())
        .gravity(-0.01)
        .charge(-1.9)
        .friction(0.9)
        .on("tick", function (e) {
            ...
        });
        force.start();
    }
```

I need to move circle (for example id=1) from the first `g` element to the second one using transition.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done.

What I did was:

1) Use jquery to append the point to the target group
2) Use a transformation (no transition) to move the point back to its original location
3) Transition the point to its new location

The jQuery was used for the `appendTo` method. It can be removed and replaced with some pure Javascript stuff, but it's quite convenient.

I've got a partially working fiddle [here.](http://jsfiddle.net/UMwRR/) The green points work right, but something is going wrong with the blue ones. Not sure why.

Comment: Nice. But after that, can you still use d3 to use data updating, inserting, removal etc? Because you basically "stole" an element from underneath d3's eyes no?

Comment: That depends on what you want to do. The data structure of the document will no longer match the structure of the elements, so anything that requires a change in the data structure won't work correctly. That being said, if you change something like which group an item belongs to, you should change the data structure to match.

Comment: In general d3 does things by mirroring the data structure to the ui. Showing something moving between groups is not reflected by the data, so it falls outside of d3's general data manipulation paradigm (and rightfully so, in my opinion.) Hence, the need for some jquery hackery to achieve the copy/paste behavior. I think it would be *better* to put all of the points in the same group if they're going to be organized in an interchangeable manner, but moving things between groups seemed like it would be fun to figure out :)

Comment: Ha you're right, you could always change the data structure in the background. If you define the identity function in data() right, d3 should be able to recognize the new element as if it had created itself, further down the road... nice!

Answer (score 0):

In my view, transitions work on a single element. If an element changes its position in the DOM tree, from below one `g` to another, I can't think of a way to make that as one smooth transition because it's basically a binary split: Now there's an element under one `g`, now it's gone but there's another one somewhere else.

What I'd do in order to achieve what I think you want to do: Group everything under the same ´g´, assign color and translation individually, then change color and translation for that single element you want to change.

But don't take that as a reliable statement that you can't do it the way you originally wanted.

Comment: I like ckersch's solution of taking a step out of d3 for this. Keeping this answer for the sake of the argument, and to see if someone proves me wrong even on the point of "not within d3"